# How do i Include Sqlite file on Setup and Deployment in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, setup-deployment

I have a VB.NET application to be deployed, but i don't know how to include my Database in Sqlite File, How to do it?

Comment: The db will be at the location specified in your connection string usually with the extension .db or .db3.  Its just a file, install it along with your app to a location like `Users` or perhaps `ProgramData`

Answer (score 0):

in solution explorer highlight the project then right click on properties then on the publish tab click on application files in there you can included all the necessary SQLite DB and DLL's.